# Dynamic cell height issue in UitableView using AutoLayout?

Tags: ios, autolayout

[image]

I have to calculate dynamic height of cell depends on two label, left label and right label. left label can have empty string . I want to give a specific fixed height if left label is empty else it will take left label height. **Cant able to give fixed height when label is empty**
This code is not working

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constraint for your both label should be,

`top,bottom,leading and trailing`.

and set below code in your `viewDidload`

```
 self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50
 self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

Answer (score 1):

Set constraints from top and bottom of the cell to both labels. 
Then add the following code in your view controller

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 50;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```